# Return all the values of an array in json

Tags: javascript, json, es5-shim

I have a json with all posts my blog and I wanna to return all the values of "tags" array. So, see the json example below:

```
"posts":[
  {
     "id":"89319077059",
     "title":"Post Title 01",
     "tags":[
        "Politcs",
        "Science",
     ]
  },
  {
     "id":"89318918989",
     "title":"Post Title 02",
     "tags":[
        "Football",
        "Soccer",
     ]
  },
]
```

So, I need to get the only tags values in loop, for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    console.info("Here [i = 0] should be show the Politcs and Science and after [i = 1] show Football and Soccer");
}
```

I tried to create a other loop to search tags and using tags[1], tags[2], etc but don't works.

```
var tags = [];

for (var tag in posts[i].tags) {
     tags.push(tag);
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand it well, you can use

- Loop:

  ```
  var tags = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; ++i) {
       tags.push(posts[i].tags);
  }
  ```
- ES5 [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

  ```
  var tags = posts.map(function(post){
      return post.tags;
  });
  ```
- ES5 `map` + ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions):

  ```
  var tags = posts.map(post => post.tag);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code :

```
var posts  = [
  {
     "id":"89319077059",
     "title":"Post Title 01",
     "tags":[
        "Politcs",
        "Science",
     ]
  },
  {
     "id":"89318918989",
     "title":"Post Title 02",
     "tags":[
        "Football",
        "Soccer",
     ]
  }
];

var tags = [];

for (var index in posts) {
    var tagsArray = posts[index].tags;
     tags.push(tagsArray);
}
console.log(tags);
```

**[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/runebame/6/)**

Comment: Note `for...in` loops are considered a bad way to iterate arrays. They will iterate all enumerable properties, including non numerical ones and those coming from prototype. And won't iterate integers between 0 and lenght-1 if there's no property, e.g. `[0,,,,,5]`

Comment: I didn't know it! Why, can you explain?

Comment: Thanks @OzerGul but I will to use maps, Oriol tips.

Answer (score 1):

In your `for (var tag in posts[i].tags)` loop, `tag` contains the keys, not the values.

So a quick fix would be:

```
for (var tag in posts[i].tags) {
    tags.push(posts[i].tags[tag]);
}
```

But as Oriol pointed out, `for..in` loops are meant to iterate through object properties, not arrays.

Just use a `for` loop like your first one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var posts = {"posts":[
  {
     "id":"89319077059",
     "title":"Post Title 01",
     "tags":[
        "Politcs",
        "Science",
     ]
  },
  {
     "id":"89318918989",
     "title":"Post Title 02",
     "tags":[
        "Football",
        "Soccer",
     ]
  },
]};


var tags = [];

for(var i=0;i<posts.posts.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<posts.posts[i].tags.length;j++) {
        tags.push(posts.posts[i].tags[j]);
    }
}

console.log(tags);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < posts[i].tags.length; j++) {
        console.log(posts[i].tags[j]);
    }
}
```

Cheers.